# Multiple SQL statements in FORALL loop

Tags: sql, oracle11g, forall

I want to insert in Different tables with only single FORALL Loop in oracle.but FORALL don't support it.any idea how can i do it??

```
   create or replace PROCEDURE test IS
      TYPE avl_web_details IS TABLE OF available_web_details%ROWTYPE;
      var_avl_web_details avl_web_details := avl_web_details();
      UNIONTABLE VARCHAR2(30000);
      TYPE RepCurTyp IS REF CURSOR; 
      Rep_cv RepCurTyp; 
   BEGIN
      UNIONTABLE := '';
  execute immediate 'update tbl_used_webuda1 set flag=1';
  FOR tbl IN (SELECT tablename FROM tbl_used_webuda1 where flag=1)
      LOOP             
    UNIONTABLE := UNIONTABLE || 'select *' || ' from ' || tbl.tablename || 'union all ';     
END LOOP;

       IF (LENGTH(UNIONTABLE) > 10) THEN
      UNIONTABLE := '( ' || SUBSTR(UNIONTABLE,1, length(UNIONTABLE)-10) || ' ) ';            
     end if;
      OPEN Rep_cv FOR 'select from_unixtime("5mintime") as "5mintime",username,host,src_zone,domain,dst_zone,content,category,url,hits ,bytes,appid ,application,categorytype,usergroup from'|| uniontable;
LOOP 
    FETCH Rep_cv BULK COLLECT INTO var_avl_web_details LIMIT 200000;
        FORALL i IN 1..var_avl_web_details.COUNT
            insert into available_web_details values var_avl_web_details(i);
    insert into web_ap_ca_co_do_ur_us_5min values(ts ,var_avl_web_details(i).application ,var_avl_web_details(i).category ,var_avl_web_details(i).content ,var_avl_web_details(i).domain ,var_avl_web_details(i).dst_zone ,var_avl_web_details(i).url ,var_avl_web_details(i).username ,var_avl_web_details(i).hits,var_avl_web_details(i).bytes,var_avl_web_details(i).appid);     
    insert into web_user_5min values(ts,var_avl_web_details(i).username,var_avl_web_details(i).hits,var_avl_web_details(i).bytes,var_avl_web_details(i).appid);
    EXIT WHEN Rep_cv%NOTFOUND; 
end loop; 
close rep_cv; 
end;**
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

FORALL is not a "loop command", it is part of the syntax for a bulk insert statement.  So the correct solution is to write the FORALL clause with each insert:

```
FORALL i IN 1..var_avl_web_details.COUNT
    insert into available_web_details values var_avl_web_details(i);

FORALL i IN 1..var_avl_web_details.COUNT 
    insert into web_ap_ca_co_do_ur_us_5min values(ts ,var_avl_web_details(i).application ,var_avl_web_details(i).category ,var_avl_web_details(i).content ,var_avl_web_details(i).domain ,var_avl_web_details(i).dst_zone ,var_avl_web_details(i).url ,var_avl_web_details(i).username ,var_avl_web_details(i).hits,var_avl_web_details(i).bytes,var_avl_web_details(i).appid);      

FORALL i IN 1..var_avl_web_details.COUNT
    insert into web_user_5min values(ts,var_avl_web_details(i).username,var_avl_web_details(i).hits,var_avl_web_details(i).bytes,var_avl_web_details(i).appid);
```

Comment: Even i am not able to call procedure inside FORALL Loop..??

Comment: It's **not** a "loop"!  No, you can only use FORALL with DML statements.

Answer (score 7):

No need to call FORALL many times. Just use INSERT ALL DML statement.

```
forall i in v_list.first..v_list.last
  insert all
    into t116 (id) values (v_list(i))
    into t117 (id) values (v_list(i))
      select 1 from dual;
```